# write code to multiline

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
foreach (var item in products)
            {
                contantProduct += "<br/> <div class='linkProduct' id=\"link" + item.IdProduct + "\" onclick=\"$('.linkFlashIco').css('background-image','url(icon/Pointer.png)');$(this).find('>:first-child').css('background-image','url(icon/Activepointer.png)'); $(this).find('>:first-child').css('background-repeat','no-repeat');  $('.linkProduct').css('font-weight','normal');$('.linkProduct').css('border','1px solid orange');$('.linkProduct').css('background-color','white');$(this).css('border','1px solid blue');$(this).css('background-color','red');$(this).css('font-weight','bold');$('.detailProduct').slideUp();$(\'#" + item.IdProduct + "\').slideToggle('normal');\" id=\"link" + item.IdProduct + "\" style='text-align: right;cursor: pointer;float: right;padding-right: 2px;border:1px solid orange;text-decoration:none' > <font   face='Tahoma'>" + item.NameProduct + "</font><div class='linkFlashIco' style='background-image: url(icon/Pointer.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;float: right;width: 18px;height: 20px;'></div></div>";

}
```

how can write `contantProduct` in multi line

i like write

```
contantProduct+="<br/><div"
+"....."
+"...."
```

Comment: wow your templating is realy crazy...

Comment: are you realy asking this @Tigran?? :)

Answer (score 2):

use the @

> contantProduct += @"
>
> <br/>
>
> <div class='linkProduct' id=""link""
>
> ... etc.
>   ";

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're getting at, you can find some answers here....
[Multiline strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You could use ejs or http://jade-lang.com/  as a templating engine. JavaScript doesn't natively support multiline strings unless you want to escape the line breaks.

```
var str = "some text \
Some more text";
```